# Radio Button Selection not showin in window.print()

Tags: javascript, printing, radio-button

Having Issues with Radio Button Selection not appearing in window.print()

HTML:

```
                <p>This is question # one, Please Select yes or no below</p>
                <input type="radio" name="Q1">Yes <input type="radio" name="Q1">No

                <p>This is question # two, Please Select yes or no below</p>
                <input type="radio" name="Q2">Yes <input type="radio" name="Q2">No

                <p>This is question # three, Please Select yes or no below</p>
                <input type="radio" name="Q3">Yes <input type="radio" name="Q3">No

                <p>This is question # four, Please Select yes or no below</p>
                <input type="radio" name="Q4">Yes <input type="radio" name="Q4">No<br><br>

                <button type="button" onclick="readySignature()">Click to Sign</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="finishSigning()">Finish Signing</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="(printNow())">Print Contract</button>
```

JS:

```
function readySignature(){
        canvas = document.getElementById("testSig");
        signaturepad = new SignaturePad(canvas);
        console.log("This Works");

}

function finishSigning(){

    var pngdata  = signaturepad.toDataURL();
    var sigArea = document.getElementById("sigArea");
    var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.src = pngdata;
    sigArea.innerHTML = "";
    sigArea.appendChild(image);

}

function printNow(){
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title  + '</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write('<h1>' + document.title  + '</h1>');
    mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById("contract").innerHTML);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();

    return true;
}
```

When printing and in the preview window the Radio Button selections are not shown. I've checked that background graphics is enabled in chrome and i've added

```
.ui-state-active {
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
}
.ui-label-active {
        font-weight: bold !important;
        font-size: 20px !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
}
```

to my CSS.

Despite all this i cannot get the radio button selections to appear in print.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
input[checked] {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
}
```

The CSS Selector used in your question (".ui-state-active") would work if you have JavaScript adding that class when the button is checked.   However, you can just use "input[checked]" and apply the "-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact" to the radio input element for checked radio box inputs.